# customer registartion success mail change via admin panel

Tags: admin, configuration, email, email-templates

1:i want to change images and text in registration successful mail where can i find it . i see admin > system > transactional mail but there are no such mails.

i could not find where to change it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saurav you can change  customer registration email templae from admin.Magento all transactional  email html template is locate at `app/locale/your language IO/template/email`

```
account_new.html
account_new_confirmed.html
```

you need change here